How to update a secret from an API Connection resource in Azure using az cli
Title sums up my problem. This is the bicep code I used to create the API Connection:
resource blobConnection1 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'blob1apiconnection'
  kind: 'V2'
  location: location
  properties: {
    displayName: 'blob1-apiconnection'
    api: {
      id: 'subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${location}/managedApis/azureblob'
      displayName: 'blob1'
    }
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'servicePrincipalAuth'
      values: {
        'token:clientId': {
          value: 'clientId'
        }
        'token:clientSecret': {
          value: 'super-secret'
        }
        'token:TenantId': {
          value: 'tenantId from other tenant!'
        }
      }
    }    
  }
}

Note: It's a connection for a Blob Connector in my workflow (logic app standard) to connect to the blob-storage in another Tenant! So I have to use servicePrincipalAuth.
I've tried to update the 'token:clientId' property with az cli in 100 ways, but nothing works. When I request the api-resource with the az cli (az resource show), it shows up, but without the 'token:clientSecret' property in its parameterValueSet.
If I deploy this api-connection with the token hardcoded, it works.
I also cannot find a possible integration with Azure Keyvault.
I also cannot find a way to update the secret using the GUI.
So my question is:
How do I update the secret from this API Connection using az cli? (The secret is rotated every x weeks, so I have to automate it...)
Any tips/help is welcome :)

I ended up creating a second pipeline just for re-deploying the API-Connections resources with the new secret. Needed to shuffle my bicep code around and introduced a new parameter to indicate that we only want to deploy the API-Connections. Not ideal. It would be better if we could just run an az cli command in this pipeline.

Are you still looking for an Azure CLI approach? @Albert Romkes
